# Is it possible find the values ​of the two variables a and x in the function y = (a ^ k) ^ (x ^ k), i know only the y and the k

Tags: function, binary, computer-science, xor

I would like to know if it is possible to create a function, using logic gates for binary numbers, such that i can go back to the two variables **a** and **x**, knowing only **y** and **k**.

I used the **XOR** logic gate but, if this is indeed possible, you can also change it to any other gate, I accept any kind of advice!

***y = (a ^ k) ^ (x ^ k)***

That's a **SAMPLE** of the function that i must find, if it can be solved in other simpler ways let me know! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

i'm assuming that ^ here means xor and not exponentiation.

Remember that ^ is both associative and commutative, so

```
y = (a ^ k) ^ (x ^ k) == a ^ x ^ k ^ k = a ^ x ^ (k ^ k) = a ^ x ^ 0 = a ^ x
```

The value of `k` is completely irrelevant in this expression, so knowing the value of `k` tells you absolutely nothing.

Knowing the values of two of `a`, `x`, or `y`, you find find the third by xor-ing the other two.  You cannot find the value of `k` if you don't know it.

Comment: i have the " k " variable, and also the " y " variable, there's a way with logic gates to link a and x in such a way as to be able to reconstruct them from the result?

Answer (score 1):

You can, in a sense. What we know about the normal math we have encountered our whole lives is not the same here, so solving for **a** and **x** will not be so explicit. Firstly, there is not a nice concept of moving variables from one side of the equation to the other in boolean algebra. Second, the XOR function is not a continuous function, therefore it can only be expressed as a piecewise function. What that all means is solving for **a** and **x** is not going to happen like we're used to.

Let's break it apart to make it more clear.

**y = f1 ^ f2**

where **f1 = (a^k)**

where **f2 = (x^k)**

All we did here was to make a smaller function for each parenthesis.

Let's define **f1** (XOR).

**f1 = 0,  a=k**

**f1 = 1,  a!=k**

Let's define **f2** (XOR).

**f2 = 0,  x=k**

**f2 = 1,  x!=k**

Now, let's define **y** (XOR)

**y = 0,  f1=f2**

**y = 1,  f1!=f2**

If you know **y**, then you can determine whether **f1** and **f2** are equal or not. Since **f1** and **f2** are constructed the same way, they are identical except for their input arguments **a** and **x**. From this point, if you know **k**, you can show that if **f1=f2**, then **a=x**. You can also show that if **f1!=f2**, then **a!=x**. You can say how **a** and **x** are related, but unfortunately, you cannot determine their values. I urge you to try plugging it in yourself, you will find **a** and **x** can have two different values for each value of **y**.

Comment: Thank you very much for the exhaustive answer, i perfectly understood the concept. Do you think there would be a way, using decimal numbers instead of binary numbers, also  normal operations instead of logic gates, to reconstruct the two variables also limiting the length of the variable y as much as possible? (maximum 30-35 digits)

Comment: I have to memorize the same variable in this way but about 100 times, its value is about 5287941256 each time, in the end I would need a not very big variable y. Thanks

Comment: @Noname I'm not totally sure I understand what your asking, but I'll give it a shot. If you had decimal numbers and normal mathematical operations, you could. You could solve for either 'a' or 'x'. Let's say you solved for 'a'. Then the other side of the equation would have 'k', 'y' and 'x'. You know the value of 'k' and 'y'. You plug in any value for 'x' that you like and that will give you the 'k' that satisfies the relation. Not sure it's necessary, but If 'x' and 'a' both had to be integers, then it would be a different situation and more difficult to solve.

Comment: I just need a function that contains itself inside before the calculation(y0) and the variable i need(x): y = y0 (something) x. First of all i need to find x wich is what a i need, and second, i need to find y0 to make the same thing, but with a different variable values, i have a round algorithm that process some calculation for 120 round,  and every round i need to reverse the function to find the variable x. I only need one function to go back to all the x variables of the calculations. What would it be like with decimals and operations?